# Unity 3D Instantiating multiple prefabs at one instead of just one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is code for instantiating

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbCag.png)

```
private void Update()
{
  
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
    {
        Shoot();
        
    }

}
  
void Shoot() {
        Instantiate(bullet, shootingpoint.position, transform.rotation);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) is true every frame the key stays pressed. You are seeing the result of various consequential frames calling `Instantiate`

=> Use [`GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) instead! It is true only in the one frame the key goes down.